# invalid Document Element 'field': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'

Tags: magento2

I am getting below Exception on Stores->Configuration Page. Is anyone know about how to fix this in magento2?

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid Document 
Element 'field': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 11
```

I found element-only on path

> vendor\magento\module-catalog\Test\Unit\Model\ProductTypes\Config_files\invalidProductTypesXmlArray.php:
>   99 "Element 'type': The attribute 'name' is required but
>   missing.\nLine: 1\n", 100 "Element 'type': Character content other
>   than whitespace is not allowed because the content " . 101: "type is
>   'element-only'.\nLine: 1\n" 102 ], 103 ] –

Comment: have you added any extension?

Comment: Yes I have added themeVast and storepickup Extension. There must be any module in theme which causing that issue but I don't know which one is that Is there any way to findout which module is causing this error becuase theme has multiple modules. I have disabled and checked storepickup module but error is same.

Comment: try to fine this `element-only` in that source

Comment: Thanks for replying Kunj I found element-only on path - vendor\magento\module-catalog\Test\Unit\Model\ProductTypes\Config\_files\invalidProductTypesXmlArray.php:
   99              "Element 'type': The attribute 'name' is required but missing.\nLine: 1\n",
  100              "Element 'type': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content " .
  101:             "type is 'element-only'.\nLine: 1\n"
  102          ],
  103      ]